# Changing checkbox value on button click - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How to change checkbox value not only by clicking on that checkbox input but on the whole button
that wraps input and span?

```
    const statuses = ["Draft", "Pending", "Paid"];

     const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(
     new Array(statuses.length).fill(false)
    );

     const handleCheckboxChange = (position: number) => {
       const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) =>
         index === position ? !item : item
       );
       setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);
     };

        {statuses.map((status, index) => (
              <button key={index}>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(index)}
                />
                <span>{status}</span>
              </button>
            ))}
```

Comment: Replace the button with a label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `handleCheckboxChange` function to the `button` and use `checked` property to `input` for handling check-uncheck dynamically. As you see, in the `checked` property I give the value dynamically like this `checked={checkedState[index]}`.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const statuses = ["Draft", "Pending", "Paid"];

  const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(
    new Array(statuses.length).fill(false)
  );

  const handleCheckboxChange = (position) => {
    const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) =>
      index === position ? !item : item
    );
    setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {statuses.map((status, index) => (
        <button key={index} onClick={() => handleCheckboxChange(index)}>
          <input type="checkbox" checked={checkedState[index]} />
          <span>{status}</span>
        </button>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

And another way is - just use `label` instead of `button`. In this case you need to give proper styles to the label.

```
  return (
    <>
      {statuses.map((status, index) => (
        <label key={index}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(index)}
            checked={checkedState[index]}
          />
          <span>{status}</span>
        </label>
      ))}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: you're right. I forgot about `checked` props.

Comment: yeah, another way of doing this - use label instead of button

Comment: I think that in example with button  there need to be an additional `onChange` event despite `onClick` on the wrapping button, because of the `checked` prop provided. If we dont do it the input remains uncontrolled and there are warnings in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the handler on the button instead of the input checkbox.
The reason is event in javascript will go from outer tag to inner tag. If you click on a button the event will fired in button before fired in button's children.
For details, see [event bubbling and capturing](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

```
<button key={index} onClick={() => handleCheckboxChange(index)}>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  //onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(index)}
                  checked={checkedState[index]} 
                />
                <span>{status}</span>
              </button>
```